# BinaryWriter C#

Tags: c#

estou com pequeno problema, 
eu uso `BinaryWriter` para escrever os bytes e depois serem enviados como resposta 
certamente eu uso de maneira certa(eu acho).

porém, quando eu uso por diversas vezes, dou breakpoint ou capturo as respostas pela *WireShark*, olhando as respostas que ele esta me retorna(Escrita)
e parece que o `BinaryWriter` está juntando todas as vezes que eu escrevo e depois envio a resposta.

vou dar um exemplo básico do código da maneira que eu uso:

```
Response.Write(new byte[] { 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00 }); //chamada da classe é Response

Response.WritePStr(UserInfo.Username); //Escreve String e converte em bytes

SendResponse(); //copia os bytes escritos da PangyaBinaryWriter, usando o Response

Response.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0xD9, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF });

SendResponse();
```

se eu deixar desta forma ele "parece" juntar tudo e envia como resposta, e as vezes ele envia tudo separado, mas é difícil isso acontecer.
meu problema é este, há alguma forma de "corta" ou "separar" para cada resposta seja individual?

Codigo está aqui:

[PangyaBinaryWriter](https://pastebin.com/bqjButYJ)

[PlayerSendPackets](https://pastebin.com/ghMktDRz)

[Player](https://pastebin.com/RBz3Hs0d)

Comment: Também não consegui entender muito bem o que você procura... mas me parece se aproximar da técnica de chunks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868279/anyone-have-sample-code-for-doing-a-chunked-http-streaming-download-of-one-web

Comment: OK, muito obrigado. irei olhar mais tarde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra mim ficou um pouco vago mas darei minha solução pelo que entendi.

Este comportamento é normal, os pacotes não são diferenciados da forma que você quer só porque você quer. 
Você mesmo deve diferenciá-los. Normalmente quando você envia dois pacotes assim, os dois chegam "juntos" e o provedor de conexão não sabe que lá existem dois pacotes.

O que se faz normalmente é o seguinte:

- Tamanho [4 bytes]
- Corpo da mensagem [Tamanho]

O corpo da mensagem é definido pelo TAMANHO, sendo assim, você sempre saberá o quanto deverá ler após receber os 4 primeiros bytes. Logo após ler os 4 primeiros + o corpo, os próximos 4 bytes serão referentes ao próximo size do pacote e assim por diante.

Basicamente:

1. leia 4 bytes = N
2. leia N bytes
3. leia 4 bytes = N
4. leia N bytes
5. .........

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, talvez seja o BinaryWriter com memorystream